# Best way to deal with UITableView of Unknown depth with Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I am creating a storyboard that will pass through an unknown depth. What I am doing is creating a loop segue from the UITableViewCell to its main view controller. and in perforSegueWithIdentifier, I am passing the info for the next level.

That all works fine, but the problem is if I want to branch off to a detail view based on that data. I have to resort to hacks with buttons and phantom view segues. Does anyone know how this should be done officially? I want to be able to link the UITableViewCell to two different controllers and then decide which one to go to in performSegueWithIdentifier. is this possible?

Comment: [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: They are embedded in UINavigationControllers, yes. Thank you google. Got any thing else?

Comment: I was actually able to get it going like this, its just a bit... chaotic. http://i.imgur.com/OrXcE.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with storyboards, but from what I know of traditional UITableView usage the cell should not be telling the view controllers what to be doing. Doing this breaks the MVC paradigm. The cell's table view's delegate (which is normally the view controller displaying the table view) will respond to the method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and will then perform the appropriate segue to the next view controller.

For showing detailed views, table view cells offer the accessory type `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`. When using this type, the table view delegate can respond to the selector `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` and then perform the necessary segue to show the detailed view.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: yea, looks like this is the best way for now

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar time ago.

I didn't find any 'official' solution, but one solution I found was to add a long press gesture recognizer to the cell, that lead the user to a detail view, in addition to the normal selection.

However the only downside is that you have in some way to inform the user of this "hidden" option.

Here's a code fragment in viewDidLoad:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *taskDetail = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showTaskDetail:)];
taskDetail.minimumPressDuration=0.5f;
taskDetail.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
[self.myTableView addGestureRecognizer:taskDetail];
```

Then in my taskDetail:

```
-(IBAction)showTaskDetail:(id)sender {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint p = [gesture locationInView:TV];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        MyManagedObj *obj = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // other operations omitted...
        // then perform segue... 
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"taskDetail" sender:indexPath];

    }
}
```

Other solution I have tried was to two a buttons in UITableViewCell, one for table drill down and the other for detail. It works also, but my cell was too small, and there were no much rooms for two buttons.